# Gluster volume create -> host not a friend

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, glusterfs, amazon-route53

If I use IPs to create Gluster volume, it works well, but when I use hostnames, it says:

```
Host glustertest1 not a friend
```

glustertest1 is Route 53 name which resolves to EC2 Instance private address.
I use glusterfs 3.3.0

**Question:** What could be the reason of this problem?

Comment: So if you ping glustertest1 on your EC2 instance does it resolve to itself?

Comment: Yes, it is pingable and I can see Instance internal address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue - before I was using SysV build, but switching to upstarted one fixed that. Use upstrated build for Ubuntu.